# MIPS Linux kernel in qemu trips on initrd

Tags: linux-kernel, mips, qemu, boot

I grabbed `initrd` and `vmlinux` (kernel 4.9.0) images from http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/Debian9.5/main/installer-mips/20170615+deb9u4/images/malta/netboot, installed and booted `Qemu` just fine:

```
$ qemu-system-mips -M malta -m 1G -hda ./debian-mips.qcow2 \
      -initrd $initrd \
      -kernel $vmlinux \
      -append "nokaslr root=/dev/sda1" -nographic
```

Then I cross-compiled fresh kernel 4.18.0 using the same config as for 4.9.0, but this time `Qemu` fails to boot:

```
...
[    4.036903] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    4.045894] rtc_cmos 70.rtc: setting system clock to 2018-07-23 02:26:58 UTC (1532312818)
[    4.076247] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1528K
[    4.076491] This architecture does not have kernel memory protection.
Loading, please wait...
starting version 232
[    4.685538] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    4.703542] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    4.754874] random: udevadm: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
Begin: Loading essential drivers ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-premount ... done.
Begin: Mounting root file system ... Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount ... Begin: Waiting for suspend/resume device ... Begin: Running /scripts/local-block ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/local-block ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/local-block ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/local-block ... done.
...
done.
Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device
done.
Begin: Waiting for root file system ... Begin: Running /scripts/local-block ...
done.
done.
Gave up waiting for root file system device.  Common problems:
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT!  /dev/sda1 does not exist.  Dropping to a shell!


BusyBox v1.22.1 (Debian 1:1.22.0-19+b3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

I believe I have all the required drivers/hardware support compiled in, since I'm using the same `.config` file. Also, I mounted my qemu image, and did `make modules_install` in there, so the image does have the correct modules matching the kernel version.

**UPDATE**

So I enabled all the drivers under `DeviceDrivers/ATA/ATAPI/MFM/RLL support (DEPRECATED)` and `DeviceDrivers/Serial ATA and Parallel ATA drivers (libata)`, rebuild the kernel, installed it in `qemu` image, booted up:

```
[    4.437168] ata2.00: ATAPI: QEMU DVD-ROM, 2.5+, max UDMA/100
[    4.442551] ata1.00: ATA-7: QEMU HARDDISK, 2.5+, max UDMA/100
[    4.443553] ata1.00: 20971520 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 
[    4.478753] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      QEMU HARDDISK    2.5+ PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    4.490907] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    4.498621] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 20971520 512-byte logical blocks: (10.7 GB/10.0 GiB)
[    4.501629] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    4.508063] scsi 1:0:0:0: CD-ROM            QEMU     QEMU DVD-ROM     2.5+ PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    4.518142] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    4.539178] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi3-mmc drive: 4x/4x cd/rw xa/form2 tray
[    4.540712] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[    4.564806] sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
[    4.569555]  sda: sda1 sda2 < sda5 >
[    4.588040] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    5.102260] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1556K
[    5.102988] This architecture does not have kernel memory protection.
Loading, please wait...
starting version 232
[    7.297015] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    7.341169] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    7.527445] random: udevadm: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
Begin: Loading essential drivers ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-premount ... done.
Begin: Mounting root file system ... Begin: Running /scripts/local-top ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount ... done.
Begin: Will now check root file system ... fsck from util-linux 2.29.2
[/sbin/fsck.ext4 (1) -- /dev/sda1] fsck.ext4 -a -C0 /dev/sda1 
/dev/sda1: clean, 29311/628320 files, 454566/2512640 blocks
done.
mount: mounting /dev/sda1 on /root failed: No such device
done.
Begin: Running /scripts/local-bottom ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ... mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
done.

    mount: mounting /run on /root/run failed: No such file or directory
run-init: current directory on the same filesystem as the root: error 0
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
run-init: current directory on the same filesystem as the root: error 0
run-init: current directory on the same filesystem as the root: error 0
run-init: current directory on the same filesystem as the root: error 0
run-init: current directory on the same filesystem as the root: error 0
run-init: current directory on the same filesystem as the root: error 0
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.
```

What else is possibly going wrong here?
Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you have no sdaX driver initialized while kernel is trying to mount rootfs. Try to run make menuconfig and make sure that your sdaX driver is built in.

Comment: @user2699113, thanks for comment. Where exactly in menuconfig/Drivers/BlockDriver (?) maze should I be looking for `sda` driver support?

Comment: It depends on your hardware. You need to know what kind of storage controller is used in your board/qemu emulator. If you don't know it I'd suggest to enable all the options in menuconfig/device drivers/serial ata and parallel ata divers (libata)

Comment: @user2699113, I updated my question with more information after I rebuilt the kernel.

Comment: I'm wondering why the kernel is trying to mount /dev/sda1 in /root directory, while it should mount it as / ?

Comment: That's the way `init` script from `initrd.img` operates. But the question is why it complains `No such device` when _there is_ `/dev/sda1` !

Comment: Please check if you have "devtmpfs" enabled in your kernel .config file.

Comment: Your mounted system doesn't contain the folders the `init` script would like to use.

Comment: @user2699113, thank you, that was one of the missing options. Somehow I missed out a couple of others. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel configuration has to include the following options for correct `FS` mount procedure :

a) `Device Drivers/Serial ATA and Parallel ATA drivers (libata)` -- CONFIG_ATA_SFF, CONFIG_ATA_BMDMA, CONFIG_ATA_PIIX

b) `Device Drivers/Generic Driver Options` -- CONFIG_DEVTMPFS